# Handlebar templates

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have array with data and When I am trying to compile it with handlebar template, I am getting error as "var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse; - option is undefined" while fetching the value of "column". 
Can someone  let me know what is been missed out here?

```
testData = [
  title : 'text1',
  values : {column: [0, 0, 0]}
]


<table>
{{#each}}
<tr>    
    <td>{{title }}</td>
    {{#each values}}
        <td>{{column}}</td> 
    {{/each}}   
</tr>
{{/each}}
</table>



var template = Handlebars.compile(tmpl_src);    
var html = template(testData);
$(body).html(html);
```

Comment: What does `testData` really look like? Is it an array or an array of objects?

Comment: testData is an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error but it looks like a Handlebars helper being called incorrectly. The most likely candidate would be your `{{#each}}` as `each` is supposed to be called with something to iterate over. We can fix that problem by calling the template function with an object so that your `testData` has a name inside the template:

```
var testData = [
    { title : 'text1', values : {column: [0, 0, 0]} },
    //...
];
var template = Handlebars.compile(tmpl_src);    
var html = template({
    rows: testData
});
```

Then a slight adjustment to the template:

```
<table>
    {{#each rows}}
        <tr>    
            <td>{{title}}</td>
            {{#each values.column}}
                <td>{{.}}</td> 
            {{/each}}   
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

I've also adjusted the inner `each` so that it iterates over the array inside `values` rather than trying to iterate over `values` itself, `{{.}}` refers to the current item so that should give you the zeroes you're after.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CRCG5/